# Why should we check for internet connectivity before making http request in android?

Tags: android

I have read somewhere that it is better to check internet connectivity before making http requests to avoid http exceptions.
Why don't we rely on http exceptions ? We can put it in try catch block and handle it.

Comment: orelse your page will looks blank.

Comment: you should check in the first request and after connection timeout... but noty after **each** http request...

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if there's no internet connection, it doesn't execute at al. If you're using a try catch, it executes everything untill it doesn't work anymore, which is simply a waste of processing code.

Answer (score 0):

This is opinion based as it is related to developers choice whether to check internet connectivity or rely on try-catch block. If you have further processes dependent on the response then you have to handle it everywhere. Instead you can check internet connectivity prior to making any http request. I personally in all my apps use broadcast receiver for connectivity change whose responses are handled in all screens by passing the local instance of interface in connectivity check task run on connectivity change broadcast. So i get results in all the screens (fragments) visible to user and i alert user likewise or handle processes likewise depending on apps requirement.